# AngularJS $http.get service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a `$http.get` service in my app, which is retrieving xml data for conversion. In my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m42wOY?p=preview) I also have a file named `data.xml` which has the same formatted xml file as in the url I entered. When I enter `data.xml` into the `$http.get` function, the data is received and my app works. When I try plugging in the url, however, it crashes. The browser tells me that I have an illegal token on the line with the url. I've looked over the documentation on the angularjs site and I can't find why I'm getting this error. I'm new to angular and don't have much experience with this service. How can I pull the data from that url?

My current code:

```
factory('DataSource', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get(
                'http://50.22.49.237/XMLFiles/ReformatedSample.xml', {
                    transformResponse: function(data) {
                        var x2js = new X2JS();
                        var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                        return json;
                    }
                }
            )
            success(function(data, status) {
                callback(data);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Normally, you can't make AJAX calls to a domain that is not the same as your page, so you would leave off the protocol/domain/port and just pass `XMLFiles/ReformatedSample.xml`.

Comment: If you do want to access that specific file from that URL, try with CORS enable on the source site to allow access OR use a JSONP call. In general this behaviour is restricted in all browsers. That could be the reason you might be getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the console? Maybe you have a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue.

Comment: Yes it gives me the following error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://50.22.49.237/XMLFiles/ReformatedSample.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." Is there a work-around?

Comment: If you are using an apache web server on the remote machine you can place this line within your .htaccess file:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: The xml file origin isn't from my machine, its on someone else's server. By changing the access would I still be able to host this page on another server? Or will it only run locally?

Comment: If you dont have access to that server, the only thing you can do is to store that file in your own server. If that file changes its content often, maybe is worth placing a cron job in your server to pull the data from there and then using your file to populate the data in your angular application.